# Convert ActiveMQBytesMessage to ActiveMQTextMessage in Java

Tags: java, spring, jms, activemq-classic

How to get ActiveMQByteMessage body in text format ?

`Boolean result = ((JmsMessage)message).getBody() instanceof ActiveMQBytesMessage;`
This `result` show it's `true`

For ActiveMQTestMessage I have to following : `(ActiveMQTextMessage) ((JmsMessage)message).getBody().getText()` which gives me required body content.

Answer (score 2):

From the ActiveMQBytesMessage you can get the message content as bytes. And then you can convert that into a String.

That is just standard java with byte[] -> String